# Creating paragraphs based on user input

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having trouble, grabbing the user input, and having the onclick operator create additional paragraphs with each click.

Here is my HTML code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang='en'>
    <head>
    <title>Add Paragraph </title>
    <meta charset='utf-8' >
    <script src="../js/addPara.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>  
    <body>
    <div>
    <input type='text' id='userParagraph' size='20'>
    </div>

    <div id="par">

    <button id='heading'> Add your paragraph</button> 
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>

Here is Javascript code: 

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("addheading").onclick = pCreate;
};

    function pCreate() {
      var userPar= document.createElement("p");
      var parNew = document.getElementById('userParagraph').value;
      userPar.innerHTML = par;
      var area = document.getElementById("par");
      area.appendChild(userPar);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
userPar.innerHTML = par;
```

should be

```
userPar.innerHTML = parNew;
```

Comment: There are more issues, for example `document.getElementById("addheading").onclick` should refer to `heading`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
> window.onload = function() {  
>   document.getElementById("addheading").onclick = pCreate;
> };
```

Where it is possible (perhaps likely) that an element doesn't exist, best to check before calling methods:

```
    var addButton = document.getElementById("addheading");

    if (addButton) {
      addButton.onclick = pCreate;
    }
```

Also, there is no element with id "addheading", there is a button with id "heading" though.

```
> function pCreate() {
>   var userPar= document.createElement("p"); 
>   var parNew = document.getElementById('userParagraph').value;  
>   userPar.innerHTML = par;
```

I think you mean:

```
    userPar.innerHTML = parNew;
```

if you don't want users inserting random HTML into your page (perhaps you do), you can treat the input as text:

```
    userPar.appendChild(document.createTextNode(parNew));
```

.

```
>   var area = document.getElementById("par"); 
>   area.appendChild(userPar);
> }
```

Your variable names and element ids don't make a lot of sense, you might wish to name them after the data or function they represent.

Answer (score 0):

I did it and it worked.

````
   <html lang='en'>
   <head>
   <title>Add Paragraph </title>
   <meta charset='utf-8' >
   <script>
    window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("heading").onclick = pCreate;
}

    function pCreate() {
      var userPar= document.createElement("p");
      var parNew = document.getElementById('userParagraph').value;
      userPar.innerHTML = parNew;
      var area = document.getElementById("par");
      area.appendChild(userPar);
}
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div>
   <input type='text' id='userParagraph' size='20'>
   </div>

   <div id="par">

   <button id='heading'> Add your paragraph</button>
   </div>
   </body>
   </html>```
````

Comment: Please, add brief explanation of what you did there. The goal here is to make people learn something new and not just copy paste your code.